# Liferay 7 + Spring MVC + JAX-RS

Tags: spring-mvc, jax-rs, liferay-7

Hello StackOverflow Community,

**Background:**

I have a Spring MVC portlet project. I want to provide a JAX-RS web service on a class. I came across the below guides to understand rest services in Liferay,

1. [Liferay documentation](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/jax-ws-and-jax-rs)
2. [Surekha Technology blog](http://www.surekhatech.com/blog/jax-rs-restful-web-services-in-liferay-dxp) - creates a project using rest template. I've created a project using spring-mvc template

I'm using maven and creating a WAR package

**Attempted:**

1. Configuring Endpoints and Extenders with the Control Panel, as described in Liferay documentation
2. Annotated the class with @ApplicationPath, @Component. Annotated the method with @GET, @Path, @Produces; as described in Liferay documentation
3. Deployed the WAR

**Issue:**

When I invoke the url - http://server:port/o/context-path/app-path/ I get the message in the browser 'No services have been found.' What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use rest module of liferay to develop rest api.

https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-1/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/t/jax-rs